# Why are my shapes being warped when scaled in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, resize

When my shape is scaled, it gets jagged and warped. I think it is because I have too many anchor points but removing them changes the shape. How do I keep the exact shape without it warping?

[image: Original and warped shape]

[image: Closeup of warped shape]

Answer (score 4):

Check in your "Transform" tab (if you can't see it go to *window/transform* ) if the option "Align to pixel grid" is ticked.

If it is, when you resize a vector, it will try and keep the shape in the grid and move the anchor points to fit.

Just select the original shape, uncheck that option and resize again.